# How do I get it to exit loading using useLazyQuery?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

First of all, hello everyone. I'm trying to improve myself with Graphql. Normally, I can display the GET_CHARACTERS variable that I define by calling useQuery. There is no problem here. But I want to display the data that will correspond to the value I entered in the input field. I used useLazyQuery for this. But here is the problem. I enter the text and then click the button. It stays on Loading all the time. It doesn't switch to display. I've also looked at other articles. I've also applied all the fetchPoliciys in useLazyQuery, but the result hasn't changed at all. I also tried notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true, and it didn't work either.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useQuery, gql, useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import Card from "./components/Card";

const GET_CHARACTERS = gql`
  query GetCharacterLocations($name: String!) {
    characters(filter: { name: $name }) {
      results {
        id
        name
        image
        location {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const App=()=> {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [getRickMorty, { loading, error, data, called }] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_CHARACTERS,
    {
      variables: { name },
    }
   );

  console.log({ data, loading, error });

  return (
    <div className="container">
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button
          onClick={() => {
            getRickMorty();
      }}
        >Search
        </button>

        {loading && <div>Loading</div>}
        {error && <div>Error</div>}

        {data?.characters?.results?.map((characters) => (
          <Card character={characters} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When opening the browser inspector network tab, what does the request payload that is sent by Apollo look like? According to [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#manual-execution-with-uselazyquery), my guess would be that you have to pass your `{ variables: … }` as an argument to `getRickMorty`.

Comment: I tried the topic you mentioned before. But the result was the same :(